# Text parsing using shell script

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I have few text files that has some key words. I have to select few lines from those files and parse it. Below is a sample file. I have to grep for "Customer" and get the line from the file.

```
13 Sun Sep  9 12:14:38 2012 : [P] Reproducer has the 167 number 
13 Sun Sep  9 12:14:38 2012 : [P] Customer has the 12.14.19.9 
13 Sun Sep  9 12:14:38 2012 : [P] Customer has the 12.14.89.9 
13 Sun Sep  9 12:14:38 2012 : [P] Reproducer has the 170 number 
13 Sun Sep  9 12:14:38 2012 : [P] Customer has the 12.4.89.16
```

I have to select only the lines that has Customer and have to parse it to get only the Timestamp (12:14:38) and the Number 12.14.19.9. I have to do this for multiple files. All the file has the same structure of the log. I have done this using the oneliner like below

```
grep Customer Neigh.log | cut -d " " -f 5- | cut -d ":" -f 1-4 | cut -d " " -f 1,8
```

But I need to do this inside a shell script. How can I do this. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you've *already* written your script.  Q: What exactly do you need to do, that you're not already doing?  What's missing from what you've already got?  What else do you need?

Comment: It is working fine .. But I need to give the file name as an argument in a shell script and acheive the same functionality.. I have not used shell script. So Just wanted to know how to do this in shell script..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
for i in *.txt; do awk '/Customer/ { print $5, $NF > FILENAME".out" }' "$i"; done
```

If you are using `BSD awk`:

```
for i in *.txt; do awk '/Customer/ { out=FILENAME".out"; print $5, $NF > out }' "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

OK -

Here's a quick'n'dirty shell script:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo Please enter a filename
else
  awk '/Customer/ {print $5, " ", $12}' $1
fi
```

1) The first line checks if the #/command line arguments "$#" is equal to 1.  If not, it prompts you to enter a filename.

2) The "awk" script is an alternative to "cut". It prints out columns 5 and 12, if and only if the line contains "Customer".

3) The $1 at the end of the "awk" command is shell argument #1, your file name.

Comment: !!! It works !!! How can i loop this for multiple files. Like I need to give variable number of arguments as file names and in each file i need to do the same operation. Basically i need to loop through the number of arguments and save the output of each in a separate output file. Can you please help that alone.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: You don't need to loop for multiple files.  You can change the check for #/arguments to `if [ $# -lt 1]`, and change "$1" to "`$*`".  This will let you specify multiple files .. or a wildcard .. in one command.  Please do give an "upvote" if you find a response helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This works for multiple files too.

```
awk '$0~/Customer/{print $5,$12}' *.txt
```